# Xcode Example DispatchFractal does not run in OS X 10.9, why

Tags: xcode, mandelbrot

DispatchFractal is a superb example of Mandelbrot calculation, graphical plotting and zoom.
And a great example of an Xcode project.

But it no longer runs on OS X 10.9, on my iMac 24 (Early 2009). Does anyone know why, and have you found a fix for the code.

Refer: Help, Documentation and API References, OS X 10.9 doc set, Performance, Sample Code,  DispatchFractal

On OS X 10.9, DispatchFractal is failing to recognise my graphics card. I get this Error:

"Your graphics hardware in not yet supported by OpenCL, Please check back later!" "Failed to open OpenCL kernel source:0.

This Xcode example used to work fine on Snow Leopard, on my iMac, but no longer works on OS X 10.9